# Libgdx are textures off screen rendered?

Tags: 2d, libgdx, textures, rendering

Let's say that my code looks like this:

```
OrtographicCamera camera=new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(true, 100, 150);
SpriteBatch spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
TextureRegion textureRegion = textureAtlas.findRegion("redCircle");
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 200, 200);
spriteBatch.end();
//This will try to render a TextureRegion outside of the OrthographicCamera's field of view
```

My question is: should I write my code so that it checks everytime the coordinates of what I am trying to draw, detects if it's offscreen, and in that case skips it (to spped up the rendering), or does Libgdx already do that for me?

Comment: I had asked the [same question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103748/drawing-textures-off-screen-optimization-required) and my conclusion was yes, you should check it yourself, because it appears that it matters. The math to check if something is in screen is very simple, so there is no point not doing it. Its a simple `if` check.

Comment: @Shiro , I have run some tests, and it seems that there's actually no need to check, as libgdx already does that. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I tried executing these 2 pieces of code: (camera is `camera=new OrthographicCamera(); camera.setToOrtho(true, 100, 100*screenW/screenH);`, and the 2 texture regions are of size 64*64, from the same textureAtlas)
Code 1: rendering on-screen

```
public void renderGameScreen(){
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    TextureRegion tr;
    for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
        if (Math.random()>0.5){
            tr = R.border;
        } else {
            tr=R.gamebackground;
        }
        spriteBatch.draw(tr, (float)(Math.random()*100), (float)(Math.random()*100));
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Versus code 2: rendering off-screen:

```
public void renderGameScreen(){
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    TextureRegion tr;
    for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
        if (Math.random()>0.5){
            tr = R.border;
        } else {
            tr=R.gamebackground;
        }
        spriteBatch.draw(tr, (float)(Math.random()*100)+200, (float)(Math.random()*100)+200);
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Notice how the two are identical except for the `spriteBatch.draw()` method, which in code 2 is offset by 200 pixels, and is therefore off screen)
Result: 
On PC, code 1 was at 10 to 30 fps. code 2 was at 50 to 60 fps.
On android code 1 was at 3-4 fps, code 2 was at 60.
So, I'd conclude that yes, libgdx does check if a texture is offscreen before rendering it. 
If there are any flaws in my test that may have caused it to give the wrong result, I'd be glad if someone could point them out.